# deleting lost objects in c#

Tags: c#, list, object, label

This is a function from a class I made that creates an object:

```
public static void CreateLabel()
{
     Label myLabel = new Label();
     // changes added to the myLabel
}
```

Now let's say that I call that function.

```
private void btnShow(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     MyClass.CreateLabel();
}
```

How do I delete 'myLabel' after I'm done with it?

```
this.Controls.Remove(myLabel); // doesn't recognise myLabel
```

Comment: There's not really enough here to understand what you're doing or what's happening. Controls added to one page aren't going to appear on another page. It sounds like you're describing a problem with *where* labels are displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're working on a Windows Forms application, you can remove a control from a Form or another control by using the [Control.ControlCollection.Remove](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.remove(v=vs.110).aspx) method. You can also use Clear to remove all controls in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Visibility = false, or you could use Tab Controls.

Comment: you see, after i call the function i can't use the labels because they're not global